# Exception has occurred: IndexError list index out of range. Introducir dato en un split

Tags: python, condiciones

-El tipo de error es este: Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range en la linea 43

- Cuando: Cuando introduzco el valor 30 en **bonoAparcar=input("Cuanto rato quieres de zona azul,puedes pagar 30, 60, 90 o 120 minutos")** linea 40

Le he dado varias vueltas y no acabo de encontrar el error, muchas gracias de antemano.

## Introduce la marca, el modelo de coche, el año, si es gasolina o diesel, si es un utilitario, una furgoneta pequeña, o una furgoneta.

```
#El programa te calculara el descuento que obtendrás entregando tu coche, para comprarte uno nuevo.
#Si es de antes del 98 se le aplicará un descuento del 10% si es posterior al 2008 tendrás un descuento de 15%.
#Si es diesel sumale otro 10% y si es gasolina 12%
#El programa debe decirte el descuento final que vas a obtener para comprar tu nuevo coche.
#El programa debe pedir al usuario que marca quiere comprar, el concesionario trabaja con: ford,toyota o wolkswagen.
#El programa debe pedir al usuario si la marca del coche que compra es: electrico,hibrido o gas
#Segun el tipo que sea podra circular en nucleos urbanos con restriccion o no
#Los peajes tambien dependen de  electrico,hibrido o gas
#Impuesto circulación descuento  electrico,hibrido o gas
#Aparcar en zona azul valdra x y a partir de x, depende del tipo, valdra y.
modeloEntrega=input("Introduce la marca, el modelo de coche, el año, si es gasolina o diesel,SEPARADO POR COMAS\n")
entrada=modeloEntrega.split(',')
marca=str(entrada[0])
modelo=str(entrada[1])
anio=int(entrada[2])
gasolinaDiesel=str(entrada[3])
print (marca,modelo,anio,gasolinaDiesel)

if anio < 1998 and gasolinaDiesel == "diesel" or gasolinaDiesel == "Diesel":
    descuento= 0.10+0.10
    print (descuento)
elif anio > 2008 and gasolinaDiesel == "gasolina" or gasolinaDiesel == "Gasolina":
    descuento= 0.15+0.12
    print (descuento)
else:
    print ("No has introducido valores validos")

modeloCompra=input("Introduce la marca, el modelo, si es electrico, hibrido o gas, SEPARADO POR COMAS\n")
entrada=modeloCompra.split(',')
marcac=str(entrada[0])
modeloc=str(entrada[1])
tipo=str(entrada[2])
print (marcac,modeloc,tipo)
peajeHora=10

if tipo == "electrico":
    print ("Puede circular en núcleo urbano sin restriccion\n")
    #print ("El minuto de zona azul vale 0,10")
    bonoAparcar=input("Cuanto rato quieres de zona azul,puedes pagar 30, 60, 90 o 120 minutos")
    entrada=bonoAparcar.split()
    mediaHora=int(entrada[0])
    unaHora=int(entrada[1])
    horayMedia=int(entrada[2])
    dosHoras=int(entrada[3])
    precioMinuto=10

    if bonoAparcar == 30 :
        bonoAparcar =  10 * 30
        descBono=input(int("Si no has estado los 30 minutos enteros, indica quantos has estado y te haremos el descuento"))
        preciobonoFinal=bonoAparcar - descBono

    elif bonoAparcar == 60:
        bonoAparcar =  10 * 60
        descBono=input(int("Si no has estado los 60 minutos enteros, indica quantos has estado y te haremos el descuento"))
        preciobonoFinal=bonoAparcar - descBono

    elif bonoAparcar == 90:
        bonoAparcar =  10 * 90
        descBono=input(int("Si no has estado los 90 minutos enteros, indica quantos has estado y te haremos el descuento"))
        preciobonoFinal=bonoAparcar - descBono

    elif bonoAparcar == 120:
        bonoAparcar =  10 * 120
        descBono=input(int("Si no has estado los 120 minutos enteros, indica quantos has estado y te haremos el descuento"))
        preciobonoFinal=bonoAparcar - descBono

elif tipo == hibrido:
    print ("Puede circular en núcleo urbano hasta 2 horas al dia")
    bonoAparcar=input("Cuanto rato quieres de zona azul, la fraccion horaria minima es media hora, y el máximo son 2 horas")

elif tipo == gas:
    print ("Puede circular en núcleo urbano hasta 4 horas al dia")
    bonoAparcar=input("Cuanto rato quieres de zona azul, la fraccion horaria minima es media hora, y el máximo son 2 horas")
```

Answer (score 1):

El error está en este fragmento de código:

```
entrada = bonoAparcar.split() # Cuando bonoAparcar = '30': entrada = ['30']
```

Como `entrada` es una lista con un único elemento (de longitud 1), al intentar obtener `entrada[1]` te da el error *Exception has occurred: IndexError list index out of range*, ya que ese elemento no existe.

Sustituye esa sentencia por esta otra:

```
entrada = list(bonoAparcar) # entrada = ['3', '0']
```

La función predefinida `list` convierte cualquier secuencia en una *lista*.

De todas formas, si introduces `'30'` te va a dar error al intentar obtener `entrada[2]` y `entrada[3]`, revisa esa parte jeje.

Mas abajo he observado que compruebas `tipo == hibrido` y `tipo == gas`. `hibrido` y `gas` aquí son variables, no `str`. Cambia estas sentencias por `tipo == "hibrido"` y `tipo == "gas"` respectivamente.

Para abordar este tipo de problemas te recomiendo que utilices la **consola interactiva de Python**.

Un saludo.